# Change custom HTML attribute with jQuery

Tags: jquery, facebook, html

What if I had somthing like this

```
<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="" data-width="292" data-show-faces="true" data-stream="true" data-header="false" colorscheme="light"></div>
```

and I wanted to use jQuery to change the attribute "colorscheme" to colorscheme="dark" and change "data-header" to data-header="false" so on and so fourth.

These changes would need to happen when clickong on a button or image or some other type of action... I can get the action part down its just how would I call for change for those specific variables if you will.

I also need help changing all the other ones like data-href, data-width, and data-show-faces

**Huge Thanks In Advance!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should write the click event over button or image like

```
$('#buttonID').click(function(){
    $(".fb-like-box").attr({ "data-href": "#", "colorscheme":"dark", "data-value": "I was updated" });
});
```

Attribute of div will update only when you click on the selected button.

Answer (score 0):

You can change any attribute by using [jquery .attr() method](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

If you are having troubles with minus symbol in attribute name, you can escape it with "".
Like this:

```
$("#SomeId").attr({ "data-href": "javascript:void(0)", "data-value": "oh hi there!" });
```